# How to push down the <div> below when dropdown menu buttons are appearing?

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I am working on that website just to learn HTML and CSS, without JS first.
So that's why I look for a solution without JS here.

When the page is smaller than 1081px in width the menu buttons on the top become a burger menu.
If clicked the menu buttons pop up below the nav bar - but - unfortunately the buttons are right on the top of the boxes below, which I want to push down when the burger menu is clicked on.
Can someone give me a hint on how to do that? I can't find any solution online without jscript.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Rakete</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav>
            <div id="navigation">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div id="logo"></div>
                    <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
                    <div id="menu">
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                        <a href="#">About Us</a>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                        <a href="#">Imprint</a>
                    </div>            
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div id="main">
            <div class="wrapper">
               <div id="top-boxes">
                   <div class="box"></div>
                   <div class="box"></div>
                   <div class="box"></div>
                   <div class="box"></div>
                   <div class="box"></div>
               </div>

            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

            </p>
         </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
}

/* Navigation */

#navigation
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
    line-height: 5em;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    top: 0;

}



#logo
{
    margin: 1em;
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
    background-size: 2.5em 2.5em;
    background-image: url("rocket.png");
    float: left;
}

/* ### Menu ### */


#menu
{   
     text-align: right;
     width: 100%;


}

#menu a
{
    margin: 0 1em;
    line-height: 5em;
    clear: right;
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}


label 
{
    margin: 1em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    display: none;
    width: 1em;
    float: right;
}

#toggle 
{
    display: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1081px) 

{
    label 
    {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #menu 
    {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
    }
    #menu a 
    {
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        margin: 0;

    }
    #toggle:checked + #menu 
    {
        display: block;
    }    
}

/* Content */

#main p
{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 2em; 
    clear: both;
}

#top-boxes
{
    text-align: center;

     display: inline-block;
}

.box
{
    width: 10em;
    height: 5em;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1em;
    margin-top: 3em;
    border: solid black 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: gray;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

Here is my code:
https://codepen.io/andy4117/pen/NWqzqxo

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Step1: This `<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` should be `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`. Notice `width-device-width>` changes to `width=device-width`

Comment: Thank you! I haven't even notice that this was wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `min-height` instead of `height` for your `#navigation` styling.

**Old**

```
#navigation {
    ...
    height: 5em;
    ...
}
```

**New**

```
#navigation {
    ...
    min-height: 5em;
    ...
}
```

Note: This solution is specific to your case. Different markup might needs different solution.

Comment: Thank you very much! By the way, do you know how to center the boxes when not on mobile devices? They are kinda more to the left than centered, even though I used text-align: center;

Comment: `#top-boxes { display: block; }`